# How to find max value of a column in a datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, type-conversion

I am trying to find the max value of a column in a datatable. Below is my code

```
var maxVal = dsloadReferralCodes.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"].AsEnumerable().Max(r =>  Convert.ToBoolean(int.TryParse(r.Field<string>("ROWNUM"), out intROWNUM)) ? (int?)intROWNUM : null);
```

and below id the error i am getting while trying to get the max value and assigning it to intROWNUM

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'

Can someone help me in resolving  the issue. This has been troubling me since long. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Error message is very clear IMO..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field `ROWNUM` is of type decimal and you are trying to cast it to string, that is why you are getting the error.

It should be:

`r.Field<decimal>("ROWNUM").ToString()`

Not really sure why you are converting to Boolean and parsing an int to int again.

Your query should be:

```
var maxVal = dsloadReferralCodes.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"]
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Max(r => r.Field<decimal>("ROWNUM"));
```

Comment: Thanks Habib, thanks for your answer. That helped me. But it looks like its throwing and error if there is no data in data table. assume if the datatable is empty without data rows this is the error. "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @user545359, you should check for table existance and if any rows exist like `if(dsloadReferralCodes != null && dsloadReferralCodes.Tables.Count > 0 && dsloadReferralCodes.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"] != null && dtReferralCodesTable.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"].Rows.Count > 0)`

Comment: Thanks again Habib. your answer helped me a lot. I apologize for the posting of answer to my question. I am a newbie for C# as well as Stackoverflow forum. This forum is really awesome.

Comment: Thanks Habib, Sorry to bug you again. I am getting the same error again. my code is as follows.  if (dsloadReferralCodes.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"] != null && dsloadReferralCodes.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
var maxVal =dsloadReferralCodes.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"].AsEnumerable().Max(r => r.Field<decimal>("ROWNUM"));
DataRow drloadReferralCodes = dsloadReferralCodes.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"].NewRow();
                drloadReferralCodes["ROWNUM"] = maxVal + 1;
                dsloadReferralCodes.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"].Rows.Add(drloadReferralCodes);}

Comment: The code above is good if there is data in my datatable. But if i am trying to add a new row through my UI its throwing the same error. "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @user545359, make sure you have instantiated your table, You may try to create a new table and then add it to the dataset

Answer (score 2):

you can get it in simple manner with [DataTable.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) :

```
DataRow [] dr = dsloadReferralCodes.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"].Select("ROWNUM= MAX(ROWNUM)");  

 if(dr !=null)
    {
     // Console.WriteLine(dr[0]["RowNum"]);
        int maxVal=Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]["RowNum"]);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Arshad, Thanks for your reply. It looks like the syntax is giving me the max row in data table. Actually i am looking to find the max value of a particular column. Suppose if column "rownum" max value is ('8','9','10','11'). I want to find the max value in these values which is '11'.

Comment: yes i did try the above solution and its returning the entire row based on the max value. Is there any way to just get the max value of the column ROWNUM?

Comment: Now i am getting the following error after using the updated code. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow[]' to 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Comment: Great this works. Now i get the Max value. Can you also please tell me how to assign dr[0]["RowNum"] to an integer. so that i can do a MAX+1 value. Sorry am a newbie to C#.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
maxVal = (decimal) dsloadReferralCodes.Tables["dtReferralCodesTable"].Compute( "Min(ROWNUM)", string.Empty );
```

(this doesn't use LINQ, so it would also work for .net 2.0)